# How to specify that a function parameter should be of a specific data type?

Tags: python, types, python-3.x, parameters, arguments

For example if you declare the following function:

```
>>> def fun(a, b):
...     a.pop()
...     a.pop()
...     b.add(a.pop())
...     return b
...
```

This function would receive any type of data, but let's supose I'd like to receive only arguments of type 'set', because for some reason inside this function I would need to use the methods add() and pop() which is found in any 'set'. How could I say that the function only accepts arguments of type 'set'?

Comment: What if someone wants to use it for a type where `pop()` and `add()` are valid operations, but isn't a `set`?

Comment: You don't - it's not Pythonic, and it's a bad idea. Python is designed around duck typing - that what something can do is more important than it's type. Try to do what you want to do, and catch the exceptions if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lattyware You should have used that as an answer it's a good point.

Comment: That's right. That's why answer doesn't need to raise an error. default behavior is already raising a human-readable error. Programmer might be thinking about implementing another function to handle different types.

Comment: Check out [pycontract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycontract/0.1.4) and [this document](http://individual.utoronto.ca/ashtopgun/Projects/Documents/Pyvolution/PyvolutionDbCReport.pdf)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that's a cool package.

Comment: @sgun: sadly though, it's a dead project. Still, there's a ton of functionality in there, that already works

Comment: Something related to Formal Methods which can't find much publicity yet. However, it is a must for high-reliable software systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check for type:

```
>>> def fun(a, b):
...     if not (isinstance(a, set) and isinstance(b, set)):
...         raise TypeError("Please only call this function with sets as the arguments")
...     a.pop()
...     a.pop()
...     b.add(a.pop())
...     return b
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to assign a type. You can do it in the function:

```
if not isinstance(item, set):
    raise TypeError()
```

If not, your code will raise an exception when illegal operation happens. It is reasonable. Or you can wrap your code in a `try...except` if you don't want an exception:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
 if isinstance(item, set):
     ...
```

This function returns Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

isinstance is one way, as others have already described.  This naturally needs to be combined with good automated tests.

You could also use Cython I believe, which has optional type declarations for function/method arguments.